# ArgumentOutOfRangeException in Azure from System.Web.HttpCachePolicy.UtcSetLastModified (DateTime utcDate)

Tags: azure, utc

A project that is deployed in Azure recently started throwing two or three of these exceptions a day. My investigation shows that this is often caused by assemblies that have future timestamps on them, generally caused by deploying to machines in other timezones ([this was a good resource](http://blog.brianhartsock.com/2009/02/21/systemargumentoutofrangeexception-at-systemwebhttpcachepolicyutcsetlastmodifieddatetime-utcdate/)). We have not had this problem before in the year+ that the app has been live, and it receives a lot more traffic than the handful of exceptions would suggest.

I redeployed with remote desktop enabled and checked the timestamps of our dlls and the contents of the \Windows\Microsoft.NET and \Windows\assembly directories, and did not find any "future" timestamps. At this point I'm stuck, and would be grateful for ideas.

Stack Trace:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>   Parameter name: utcDate
>     at System.Web.HttpCachePolicy.UtcSetLastModified(DateTime utcDate)
>     at System.Web.HttpCachePolicy.SetLastModified(DateTime date)
>     at System.Web.UI.Page.InitOutputCache(OutputCacheParameters cacheSettings)
>     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
>     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>     at System.Web.Mvc.OutputCacheAttribute.OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
>     at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
>     at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
>     at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
>     at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
>     at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass27.b__24(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>     at System.Web.Mvc.AsyncController.<>c__DisplayClass19.b__14(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>     at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
>     at System.Web.Mvc.AsyncController.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>     at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
>     at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>     at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
>     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. I looked at the System.Web.HttpCachePolicy and System.Web.UI.Page code (via SSCLI) and saw that this should be impossible. That exception gets thrown when you try setting the last modified date to a date that's in the future (greater than DateTime.UtcNow). This should never happen as the framework uses HttpContext.Timestamp, which is set to DateTime.UtcNow at the start of the request. A possible explanation may be NTP (time syncing) kicking in while the request is being processed?

Comment: Are you storing any data in table storage, See whether Datetime is in correct format with UTC time. Also check Converting Datetime to string and test it

Answer (score 0):

Timezone issues are really a headache in Azure Environment so I suggest you to add a startup task and change Azure Environment's timezone. I'm not claiming this will resolve your problem but it doesn't hurt to try does it? To change Timezone of your Azure Environment:

1) Save `tzutil /s "Pacific Standard Time"` as .cmd and include the file to your project.

2) In properties screen of the file, choose "Copy Always" as your Copy to Output option and "None" as your Build Action.

3) Add the following to your ServiceDefinition file:

```
<Startup>
    <Task commandLine="nameOfFileYouCreated.cmd" executionContext="elevated" />
</Startup>
```

4) And of course adapt your DateTime references in your project, you don't have to deal with conversions etc.